# unable to load background image on body using webpack 4 in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

in my react js app I want to add the **background image** on the *body*.it is working fine when I'm doing in development mode but when comes to production it is not working.
for production, I'm using `dist` separate folder may it is creating some path issue.
here **my scss**

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: $m-size;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(/images/bg4.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top; 
    background-size:cover;
}
```

my **webpack.config**

```
module.exports = {
    entry:{
      vendor: VENDOR_LIBS,
      main: './src/app.js',
    },
  output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',  
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      { test: /\.bundle\.js$/, use: { loader: 'bundle-loader', options: {lazy: true} } },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
                loader: 'css-loader?url=false',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }

        ]
    },{
        test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png|ttf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=[name].[ext]",
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {} ),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.[contenthash].css',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      favicon: './public/images/fav.ico'
    }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
      }),

  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 2
        },
      }
    },
    runtimeChunk: true,
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: {
            inline: false
          }
        }
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ],
  },
};
```

webpack generating other images into **base64** but not for this image.and it is not available in `dist` folder.

can any one help me out, i searched lot of questions but couldn't solve. 
**i don't want any external link to load image**.

Comment: After you build and your dist folder is created, can you create dist/images/bg4.png then only run your server and see if it finds the image? if so, i can tell you a more permanent solution

Comment: i'm unable to create `dist/images/bg4.png` but other images in the appilcation generating and working fine......

Comment: I dont understand. You cant go into the dist folder, create a folder named images, then copy bg4.png into to test it? Also other relative image paths work in productive, or just in development?

Comment: @ShawnAndrews yeah after creating and pasting image it is working fine but every time clean that folder whenever i need to build new production code.

Answer (score 0):

In production your current directory will change to `/dist/index.html` so thats why the path you used for development `/images/bg4.png` can't find the file.

The solution is to copy your static image files, like your background, into the `/dist` folder in the build process.

Assuming your project directory is similar to the following:

```
...
/images/bg4.png
package.json
```

Then add these commands to your webpack build script to copy the images into your production directory `/dist`.

```
// in package.json
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "...your webpack build commands... && cp -a images\\. dist\\images",
    ...
},
```

Your new file directories will look like

```
/dist/...your index.html, bundles, etc...
     /images/bg4.png
/images/bg4.png
package.json
```

and your image path should find the image file now.